# Can't find the ID from a ObjectId and import is not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, mongodb

Im getting this Error:

> ERROR TypeError: answerID.equals is not a function

Any i do not understand why.

Here is the code:

```
import { ObjectId } from 'bson';
export class Person{
   personID: ObjectId;
   constructor(personID: ObjectId){
        if(personID.equals("12345"){
           this.personID = personID;
        }
   }
}
```

Just all methods from the import are not working. Dont understand why, i installed it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectId` class expects another `ObjectId` instance as an argument, not a string.

```js
import { ObjectId } from 'bson';

export class Person {
  personID: ObjectId;

  constructor(personID: ObjectId) {
    // Create an ObjectId instance for comparison
    const targetPersonID = new ObjectId("12345");

    if (personID.equals(targetPersonID)) {
      this.personID = personID;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okei but now i am getting the following error:
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)

I also implemented the topLevelAwait in the tsconfig.json file at angularcompiler. Not working.

Comment: It is another question. It seems that you are trying to use the top-level `await` feature, which is an experimental feature in Webpack. I don't see any `await` usage in your provided code.